# MinHash Implementation Spark

Tags: apache-spark, minhash

I am trying to implement the MinHash Algorithm as described in [chapter 3](http://infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/mmds/ch3.pdf) as simple as possible in Spark.
I have searched a lot everywhere. Well i decided to follow an implementation from [this](http://matthewcasperson.blogspot.gr/2013/11/minhash-for-dummies.html) blog as Bill Dim proposes: https:  //blog.cluster-text.com/tag/minhash/
I just feel something is wrong with my implementation or i misunderstood.
What I have done so far is:

- document => n-grams
  (i use 9-grams(letters) as said in the book, but it can be changed to 5-words as proposed by Bill Dim)
- n-grams => MurMurHash3 (So thats Hased NGrams for Every Document)
- HashedNGramsRDD => Find Min(NGram) for every Document
- HashedNGramsRDD ^ (199 Random Numbers) and take min = 199 minimuns of the Xored HashedMurMurNGrams.
- So I have 200 minimus at total. and thats my MinHash Signature. Is this correct? please help! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this for fun or an actual problem that you are trying to solve (my answer might vary)?

Comment: You are welcome! Now, the follow up is: Is your task 'implementing minhash' or 'finding similar documents' (possibly using minhash/lsh and external libraries)?

Comment: @Gevorg my task involves implementing MinHash and LSH. If you **read** my initial post, I am trying to implement MinHash as described in that blog, so to continue with LSH. **IF you read...**